# Looking for information on Grandfather's WW1 Service record

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1

[image] I am hoping someone can help me find my grandfather's World War 1 records from Germany. A family photo we have of him with his regiment shows: I. Korporalschaft IV Ers. Batterie Fuss.Art.R3" Any help locating his war records would be a true gift to our family. My father is the only person in his family to have survived the holocaust and we never had any records from his time in WW1. My father just turned 90 years old. His father, my grandfather, Julius Salomon died in Poland in World War II. He was born on February 26, 1899.  My grandfather's photo has he small x above it.